# Least amount of time US government needs to pass a law?

Tags: united-states, senate, legislative-process, house-of-representatives

Assuming control of both House and Senate, but this is a bill opposed by opposition, and leaving aside fast-track procedure what is the fastest this can be done?

I am thinking this is dependent on gag rule?

Comment: Asking about both the US and Canada in one question is definitely too broad. And you need to be more clear about the scenario you're talking about

Comment: I set a few assumptions, what would you be missing to answer to either?

Comment: I would suggest splitting this into two questions, one about Canada and one about the United States.  Both of their legislative processes are completely different.

Comment: Does the party in favor of the bill also control the Presidency? Do they have the >60 votes in the Senate to overrule a filibuster, or do they only have a >50 majority? What do you mean by fast-track procedure?

Comment: I guess those are all thing I would love to learn about and contribute to the answer! Will change question to focus on the US, but please have a go at it @divibisan

Comment: This is an odd question. There isn't any lower limit I'm aware of, aside from the pragmatic necessities of crafting a bill, calling and executing votes in both houses, and obtaining the president's signature. Theoretically a bill could go from zero to law within the scope of a working day, with a bit of coordination. But that theoretical limit is patently ridiculous, and the constraints are mostly things like discussion patterns, committee delays, revisions, and paperwork logjams. but those are all imponderables. I mean, how long does it take for people to work things out together?

Comment: I guess I meant if the opposition doesn't hold majority in any chamber is opposing the bill and do whatever they can to delay it, knowing it will somehow pass, how fast/slow would the party with majority in both chamber (and presidency) would be able to get the bill to law

Answer (score 1):

#### Short answer

Very, very fast, assuming you have >50% of the house supporting you, >=60% of the senate supporting you, and the president supporting you

#### Long answer

First somebody must draft the law, pass it in the house, pass a cloture vote in the senate, pass the bill in the senate, and then have the president sign the bill. Assuming everybody is on board with the bill and knows to rush completion that way, it will probably take multiple hours. This is because it will take time to get everything done, and all of the aforementioned steps to getting the bill passed take time in between them, so in reality it will probably take a while.

Comment: A good case in point involves declarations of war which are often passed very swiftly after a decisive event, but usually with a handful of members of Congress and/or the Senate opposing the bill.

Comment: 60% support in the senate is sufficient; it doesn't need to be greater than 60%.

Comment: @phoog edited it :)

Comment: And if the bill is budget-related, then only 50 Senators plus tie-breaking VP vote or 51 Senators, is needed to pass. [More about budget reconciliation here](https://www.brookings.edu/blog/up-front/2021/02/05/what-is-reconciliation-in-congress/).